Draw Border On All Pages Using iText7 it break the loop while getting page size
after adding 1 table i'll break and move the focue to the next of the page and add the next table to tha new page then trying to appling border to all that pages it.
My code
`
table = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
table.SetFontSize(textSize + 4);
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("xyz ")).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
document.Add(table);
document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
table = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
table.SetFontSize(textSize + 4);
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("abc ")).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
document.Add(table);
 DrawBorderOnAllPages(pdfDocument);
  private void DrawBorderOnAllPages(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
  {
      int numberOfPages = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
      for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
      {
          PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
          Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();

          PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
          float x = 10;
          float y = 10;
          float width = pageSize.GetWidth() - 20;
          float height = pageSize.GetHeight() - 20;
          Color borderColor = ColorConstants.BLACK;
          float borderWidth = 1;

          pdfCanvas
              .SetLineWidth(borderWidth)
              .SetStrokeColor(borderColor)
              .Rectangle(x, y, width, height)
              .Stroke();
      }
`

shows error while getting page size
i'll try everythig but it not work
